# remove, move and rename nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, move, rename

I need rename all nodes <'record> in <'array>. The name should be the same as the name of its array. Then move <'record> +1 up. And finally remove array.

This is my xml:

```
<IDataXMLCoder version="1.0">
  <record javaclass="xxx">
    <value name="errorCode">0</value>
    <array name="service" type="record" depth="1">
      <record javaclass="xxx">
        <value name="serviceName">PT</value>
        <value name="serviceId">99</value>
        <value name="serviceInternalId">8</value>
        <value name="packageSymbol">8888</value>
        <value name="serviceComment">RT</value>
        <value name="serviceNameInChannel">RT</value>
        <value name="serviceActivationParam">NOW</value>
        <value name="serviceDeactivationParam">NOW</value>
        <null name="estimatedProcessingTime"/>
        <null name="virtualService"/>
      </record>
      <record javaclass="zzz">
        <value name="serviceName">RK</value>
...
```

This should looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><IDataXMLCoder>
  <record>
    <errorCode>0</errorCode>
    <service>
      <serviceName>PT</serviceName>
      <serviceId>99</serviceId>
      <serviceInternalId>8</serviceInternalId>
      <packageSymbol>8888</packageSymbol>
      <serviceComment>RT</serviceComment>
      <serviceNameInChannel>RT</serviceNameInChannel>
      <serviceActivationParam>NOW</serviceActivationParam>
      <serviceDeactivationParam>NOW</serviceDeactivationParam>
      <estimatedProcessingTime/>
      <virtualService/>
    </service>
    <service>
      <serviceName>RK</serviceName>
...
```

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">

    <!--copy all-->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--change record's name to service-->
    <xsl:template match="array/record">
        <xsl:element name="service">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--node name as attribute's name-->
    <xsl:template match="*[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now i see nodes <'record> as <'service> but i don;t know how move up and delete the array.

Comment: Which bits are not working? the result looks like it fulfils some of your needs. Make it a bit easier for someone to answer your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `<array name="service"..>` element is being processed by your last template, and is adding in an extra `<service>` element. Just add this template to remove it:

```
<xsl:template match="array[@type='service']">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

This will override the more specific `match="*[@name]"` template match when placed after it.

Comment: well i pasted and edited this before last template:     <xsl:template match="array[@name='service']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template> with no result

Comment: It needs to be after it, sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: It's just an order of precedence thing; that element would match either template, so it picks whichever template comes last.